# Is a class template's name in scope for a qualified out-of-line destructor's definition?

Tags: c++, templates, clang, clang++

Recent versions of clang (since `clang-11`) issue a warning when compiled with `-pedantic` for the following segment of code:

```cpp
namespace foo {
    template <int A>
    struct Bar {
        ~Bar();
    };
} // namespace foo 

template <int A>
foo::Bar<A>::~Bar(){}
```

With the generated warning (and error with `-Werror`) being:

```
<source>:10:12: error: ISO C++ requires the name after '::~' to be found in the same scope as the name before '::~' [-Werror,-Wdtor-name]
foo::Bar<A>::~Bar(){}
~~~~~~~~~~~^~
           ::Bar
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rE66vdEve)</kbd>

`clang` is the first compiler I've seen to issue this diagnostic, and as far as I'm aware, what was written above is completely valid C++. Two different ways that seem to suppress this is to either [define within the same namespace](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/s9W3vbKj5) *or* [explicitly qualify the destructor name](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ovxdbMTxe) -- such as:

```cpp
...
template <int A>
foo::Bar<A>::~Bar<A>(){}
```

**Is Clang's diagnostic here correct?** It's my understanding that the type's name would absolutely be in the correct name-scope as `foo::Bar<A>::~` -- and that the qualification of `~Bar<A>()` should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I have learned since posting the question, this warning is, strictly-speaking, correct -- though it most likely a defect in the  wording of the standard.

According to Richard Smith in [LLVM Bug 46979](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46979#c1):

> The diagnostic is correct, per the standard rules as written; strictly-speaking, the C++ rules require this destructor to be written as
>
> ```cpp
> template<typename T>
> A::B<T>::~B<T>()
> ```
>
> Per C++ [basic.lookup.qual]p6:
>
> > In a qualified-id of the form:
> >
> > `nested-name-specifier[opt] type-name :: ~ type-name`
> >
> > the second type-name is looked up in the same scope as the first.
>
> This means that the second B is looked up in class A, which finds only the class template B and not the injected-class-name.
>
> This is not an especially useful rule, and likely isn't the intended rule, which is why this diagnostic (along with a bunch of similar diagnostics for plausible but formally incorrect destructor names) is disabled by default but included in -pedantic.

Looking further into this, I can find the mentioned passage for [[basic.lookup.qual]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.qual#6) in the C++20 standard, but it appears drafts for C++23 have changed this -- which points towards this most likely being a defect.

In drafts for [basic.lookup.qual] for C++23, this whole section has been overhauled and is currently, at the time of writing, replaced with [[basic.lookup.qual]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lookup.qual#general-4) which states:

> If a qualified name Q follows a ~:
>
> **(4.1)** If Q is a member-qualified name, it undergoes unqualified lookup as well as qualified lookup.
>
> **(4.2)** Otherwise, its nested-name-specifier N shall nominate a type.
> If N has another nested-name-specifier S, Q is looked up as if its lookup context were that nominated by S.
>
> **(4.3)** Otherwise, if the terminal name of N is a member-qualified name M, Q is looked up as if ~Q appeared in place of M (as above).
>
> **(4.4)** Otherwise, Q undergoes unqualified lookup.
>
> **(4.5)** Each lookup for Q considers only types (if Q is not followed by a <) and templates whose specializations are types.
> If it finds nothing or is ambiguous, it is discarded.
>
> **(4.6)** The type-name that is or contains Q shall refer to its (original) lookup context (ignoring cv-qualification) under the interpretation established by at least one (successful) lookup performed.
>
> [Example 4:
>
> ```cpp
> struct C {
>   typedef int I;
> };
> typedef int I1, I2;
> extern int* p;
> extern int* q;
> void f() {
>   p->C::I::~I();        // I is looked up in the scope of C
>   q->I1::~I2();         // I2 is found by unqualified lookup
> }
> struct A {
>   ~A();
> };
> typedef A AB;
> int main() {
>   AB* p;
>   p->AB::~AB();         // explicitly calls the destructor for A
> }
> ```
>
> — end example]

<sup>(The full quote has been posted here since this is from a draft, and the wording may be subject to change in the future)</sup>

This appears to explicitly correct this issue by ensuring that lookup is performed as one would expect.

So basically the diagnostic is correct under older versions of C++ due to a defect in the wording -- but C++23 appears to change that. I am not sure whether this will be retroactively fixed in older versions as a defect given that it appears no compiler actually follows this pedantic requirement.