# Why does clang warn about namespaced out-of-line destructor definition?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, compiler-warnings

I've got some C++ code that boils down to this:

```cpp
namespace A {
    template <typename T>
    struct Foo {
        Foo() = default;
        ~Foo();
        void bar();
    };
}

template <typename T>
void A::Foo<T>::bar() {}

template <typename T>
A::Foo<T>::~Foo() {}

int main() { return 0;}
```

When compiled with Clang 11 or later with `-pedantic` or `-Wdtor-name` enabled (seemingly regardless of standards version), I get a warning about the out-of-line definition of the destructor:

```
<source>:14:10: warning: ISO C++ requires the name after '::~' to be found in the same scope as the name before '::~' [-Wdtor-name]
A::Foo<T>::~Foo() {}
~~~~~~~~~^~
         ::Foo
```

GCC and MSVC don't seem to emit such a warning.

So, my (compound) question:

**What is the standard worried about specifically regarding destructors to state this requirement, and why does it not apply to other member function definitions?**

Since the warning does not appear when `Foo` is a concrete type, why does it only apply when `Foo` is a class template?

Obviously, without the `namespace`, the scoping issue just goes away.

Further, is there a way to write this out-of-line destructor definition that would appease Clang and avoid generating a warning? Is this just a bug in Clang (persisting across versions 11-14+)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68751682/is-a-class-templates-name-in-scope-for-a-qualified-out-of-line-destructors-def similar?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be exactly it. Thank you!